# Ignore Missing XML Element

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I'm obtaining the values on many XML files using the below line of code.  However, I notice some of the  XML file are missing the "DateOfBirth" elements which is throw a value cannot be null.  Is there a way to ignore element and assign a blank value if the  element is missing from the XML file?  As you can see I have a loop at then I add these record to a grid.  If the DateOfBirth element is missing, it will ignore this record and not add it to the DataSet.  I want it to still add the FirstName and LastName and leave the DOB blank.

```
   foreach (object o in listBox2.Items)
   {
       DataSet objDataSet = new DataSet();

        objDataSet.ReadXml(folder + "\\" + o.ToString(), XmlReadMode.InferSchema);
        try
        {
            List<object> firstNames = objDataSet.Tables["FirstName"].AsEnumerable().Select(r => r["Part"]).ToList();
            List<object> lastNames = objDataSet.Tables["LastName"].AsEnumerable().Select(r => r["Part"]).ToList();
            List<object> dob = objDataSet.Tables["DateOfBirth"].AsEnumerable().Select(r => r["FullDate"]).ToList();
```

Adding the XML:

```
      <OmdCds xmlns="cds"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:cdsd="cds_dt"
    xsi:schemaLocation="cds ontariomd_cds.xsd">   
  <PatientRecord>
    <Demographics>
     <Names>
      <cdsd:LegalName namePurpose="L">
      <cdsd:FirstName>
        <cdsd:Part>SARAH</cdsd:Part>
        <cdsd:PartType>GIV</cdsd:PartType>
        <cdsd:PartQualifier>BR</cdsd:PartQualifier>
      </cdsd:FirstName>
      <cdsd:LastName>
        <cdsd:Part>GOMEZ</cdsd:Part>
        <cdsd:PartType>FAMC</cdsd:PartType>
        <cdsd:PartQualifier>BR</cdsd:PartQualifier>
      </cdsd:LastName>
      <cdsd:OtherName>
        <cdsd:Part>GABRIELA</cdsd:Part>
        <cdsd:PartType>GIV</cdsd:PartType>
        <cdsd:PartQualifier>BR</PartQualifier>
        </cdsd:LastName>
     </cdsd:LegalName>
   </Names>
    <DateOfBirth>
        <cdsd:FullDate>1950-03-26</cdsd:FullDate>
    </DateOfBirth>
```

Comment: get it value first and check if it's `string.nullOrEmpty`?

Comment: Also, you have a _table_ named `FirstName`? That's a strange XML format.

Comment: Also, maybe you'd be better off manipulating the XML directly instead of playing with a `DataSet`.

Comment: What does your XML look like?

Answer (score 0):

I solve the above problem myself.  I create a bool method  to check if the element exist or not. Base on true or false, I either  ignore to  get the value for the  elements.

```
  public bool IsNodeExist(string  fileName)
    {
        bool bState = false;
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(fileName);
        //Select the node with the matching attribute value.
        XmlNode nodeToFind;
        XmlNamespaceManager namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);

        namespaceManager.AddNamespace("cdsd", "cds_dt");
        namespaceManager.AddNamespace("cds", "cds");
        nodeToFind =     doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("./cds:PatientRecord/cds:Demographics/cds:DateOfBirth", namespaceManager);

        if (nodeToFind == null)
        {
            bState = true;
        }
        return bState;
    }
```